# Vue filter with options

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use one instance of a filter to be able to accept different formats. Not really sure what I'm missing. The first instance is working. The second one keeps giving an error (both of the second ones)

```
=== main.js ===
Vue.filter('formatDate', function (value, config) {
  console.log('test');
  if (config === 'time') {
    return format(value, 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm');
  } else {
    return format(value, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
  }
});

=== Page.vue ===
-- first instance -- <p> {{ item.date | formatDate }} </p>

-- second instance -- <p> {{ item.date | formatDate 'time' }} </p>
-- also second instance -- <p> {{ item.date | formatDate, 'time' }} </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
{{ item.date | formatDate('time') }}
```

as described in the Vue.js doc about filters : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Answer (score 0):

Pass `time` as a parameter to `formatDate` filter, so the syntax should be `item.date | formatDate('time')`. see [Vue filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html).

```js
Vue.filter('formatDate', function (value, config) {
  if (config === 'time') {
    return 'with time';
  } else {
    return 'default';
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    item: {
      date: new Date()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <p> {{ item.date | formatDate('time') }} </p>
</div>
```